# Is there a way to print attribute values at specific distance in front of list items?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I have massive XML files that I am converting to FO to print to PDF.  In one section, I have subsections that contain a bunch of lists.  Some of the list items have attributes that refer to pre-text.

I tried to include a table in the page master but the border at the bottom of every page was missing (since it was continuing on to the next page).

I now have it printing a two-column table where the pre-text should be in first column and the list text in second column, but instead, the pretext is in the second column with the list text. I tried to use negative padding to move it to the first column but that obviously didn't work.

I need this:

```
    <list>
        <list-item attribute1="yes" attribute3="yes"> Example text </list-item>
        <list-item attribute2="yes" attribute3="yes"> Example text again </list-item>
    </list>
```

to print to PDF like this:
(To be clear, the numbers from the attributes have to be in a running box).

---

|1   3 |     1.) Example text
|  2 3 |     2.) Example text again

I am not locked into any one particular method to solve this problem, other than I must achieve the specified layout using XSL:FO.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can force borders at breaks, look for border precedence attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you think of it as a list, then do it as a list.  You can put any block-level FO in an `fo:list-item-label` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_list-item-label).  This includes tables.

Slide 28 from my XML Prague 2016 paper at http://archive.xmlprague.cz/2016/files/presentations/css-xsl-fo-notes.pdf shows a formatted example of a table in an `fo:list-item-label` (although the example is admittedly contrived).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and the value of your paper, but I don't think it'll work for my case.  I need the table to start on a page at the first item with the attribute and keep running through the rest of the pages until it is closed.  The table needs to have a border at the end of each page, and a header at the beginning of each page. and Some items without the attribute appear within the lists.